# Flatten and JOIN data to a view to show historical values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got 2 data sets that I need to combine together... well, many more than 2, but 1 is a view that is already set up and then 1 table I've been tasked with adding to the view to make it more "historical".

The current view has a lot of columns, but the data (`dbo.vw_Site_Levels`) affecting what I need looks like this:

```
| Facility_Id | Site_Id | Grd_Val | Top_Val |
| ----------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 701.23  | 855.21  |
| 7552        | 2-BCH   | 701.23  | 855.21  |
| 7552        | 3-BCH   | 614.86  | 716.74  |
| ...         | ...     | ...     | ...     |
```

but apparently, depending on the date, the `Grd_Val` and `Top_Val` may actually be incorrect, so I'm supposed instead bring in a table, `dbo.Measure_Data`, with this structure:

```
| Facility_Id | Site_Id | Date                    | Desc | Val     |
| ----------- | ------- | ----------------------- | ---- | ------- |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2015-09-03 00:00:00.000 | GRD  | 683.00  |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2015-09-03 00:01:00.000 | TOP  | 826.49  |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2016-04-04 00:00:00.000 | GRD  | 701.23  |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2016-04-04 00:01:00.000 | TOP  | 843.87  |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2017-01-05 00:01:00.000 | TOP  | 855.21  |
| ...         | ...     | ...                     | ...  | ...     |
```

to flatten and display the historical values of `Grd_Val` and `Top_Val` with dates, to look like this:

```
| Facility_Id | Site_Id | Date       | Grd_Val | Top_Val |
| ----------- | ------- | ---------- | ------- | ------- |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2015-09-03 | 683.00  | 826.49  |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2016-04-04 | 701.23  | 843.87  |
| 7552        | 1-BCH   | 2017-01-05 | 701.23  | 855.21  |
| ...         | ...     | ...        | ...     | ...     |
```

I'm aware of the 1min difference in the dates on `Measure_Data`, I'm not in control of the data and it is only there because it needs to be a unique combination of `Facility_Id`, `Site_Id`, and `Date`.

Can anyone help me? I've tried a few things that don't seem worth mentioning as they didn't come close to what I needed, and while I did get close with one, I think, my computer reset and lost my query (I was doing a `GROUP BY` on something and I think a self-join to flatten the data but it was on Friday and I can't remember).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    md.Facility_Id,
    md.Site_Id,
    [Date]  = CAST(md.[Date] AS DATE),
    Grd_Val = MAX(CASE WHEN md.[Desc] = 'GRD' THEN md.Val END),
    Top_Val = MAX(CASE WHEN md.[Desc] = 'TOP' THEN md.Val END)
FROM dbo.Measure_Data md
GROUP BY
    md.Facility_Id, md.Site_Id, CAST(md.Date AS DATE)
ORDER BY
    md.Facility_Id, md.Site_Id, CAST(md.Date AS DATE);
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I never really thought to do the `CASE` within the aggregate function and was overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIVOT operator to do this.

```sql
DECLARE @facility table( Facility_Id int, Site_Id varchar(10), Datev datetime, Descr char(3), Val decimal(5,2))
INSERT INTO @facility
values
(7552        ,'1-BCH','2015-09-03 00:00:00.000','GRD',683.00),
(7552        ,'1-BCH','2015-09-03 00:01:00.000','TOP',826.49),
(7552        ,'1-BCH','2016-04-04 00:00:00.000','GRD',701.23),
(7552        ,'1-BCH','2016-04-04 00:01:00.000','TOP',843.87);

select Facility_Id, Site_Id, dt as [date], grd as grd_val, [top] as top_val from 
(select Facility_Id, Site_Id, cast(datev as date) as dt, Descr, val from @facility) as t
pivot
(sum(val)
for descr in ([GRD],[TOP])
)as pvt
```

| Facility_Id | Site_Id | date | grd_val | top_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7552 | 1-BCH | 2015-09-03 | 683.00 | 826.49 |
| 7552 | 1-BCH | 2016-04-04 | 701.23 | 843.87 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. I picked the other answer because it is more simple for me to understand, but +1 for the contribution!

Comment: @Daevin, no problem. Glad you liked it.